# Query DataGridView from Thread using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, winforms, linq-to-objects

I have a couple of questions. I have a DataGridView that contains data that needs to be loaded to an SQL database. It takes awhile to load the data, so I would like to load it from a background task and display a "loading" form while the data loads. I created a separate form to display "loading" and was planning to use it to actually load the data through a background task kicked off in the forms OnLoad event. I am currently loading from the main form and of course the UI is blocked until the process completes.

My current LINQ Query looks like this

```
For Each row In (From r In dgvData.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
                    Select serialnumber = r.Cells("Serial_Num"),
                    scode = r.Cells("S_Code"), sl = r.Cells("Sl_Code"), id = r.Cells("Part_id"))
...
Next
```

How can I run a thread-safe LINQ query against the DataGridView from a separate thread? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish multithreading. This is just one. You can also try `Async/Await` or the `Threading.Thread` class, but this is a simple example.

Load the data into a List, then process it on a background thread

```
' the only access to the dgv on the UI thread
' the ToList() call defeats deferred execution, 
' and iterates (gets all the rows) on the spot
Dim tmpRows = Me.dgvData.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow)().ToList()

' will run in the background
Dim a As Action =
    Sub()
        For Each row In tmpRows
            ' load into sql
        Next
    End Sub

' will happen when the background thread has completed
Dim c As AsyncCallback =
    Sub()
        MessageBox.Show("Done")
    End Sub

' Action.BeginInvoke automatically spawns a background thread
' for the action to run on.
a.BeginInvoke(c, Nothing)

' do other things while the background thread works...

' the background will complete somewhere down here 
' (or outside of this block entirely)
```